# Is it possible to get or generate event for AMI availability (without polling)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, amazon-ami, rate-limiting

I'm doing large number of AMI copying to different regions, and calling describe image from image waiter at the end of copying to make sure successful copying, the large number of describe image calls are being heavily rate limited. I know there are EC2 instance state change events, I wonder if it is possible to generate AMI available/ready event, if yes I can use the event to trigger a message to my SQS, from which I can get notification and avoid making the describe image calls.

My search so far does not find any AMI events, in case I missed something, does anyone know if it is possible to generate AMI available/ready events? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like there are [Amazon CloudWatch Events for Amazon EBS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-cloud-watch-events.html) (eg Snapshot creation), but not for AMI creation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering my owner question.

AMi ready events can be generated in CloudWatch:

```
rules->create new rule
  Service name: EC2
  Event Type: EBS Snapshot Notification
  Specific event(s): copySnapshot
  Specific result(s): succeeded
```

Hope this helps someone with similar need.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateImage"
    ]
  }
}
```

this will capture ami create event if cloudtrail enabled