# Lambda Function to create a Launch Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS and trying to create a lambda function to create a launch template daily. So we have a lambda function that is currently creating daily AMI's of EC2 instances that we are running. Is there any way to automatically run a lambda function daily to create a launch template using the latest created AMI as soon as the daily AMI creation as completed and also delete the old launch templates after certain days?

Answer (score 0):

So you create an event rule as shared in this question [is-it-possible-to-get-or-generate-event-for-ami-availability-without-polling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57748014/2246345).

And then hook your lambda function for creating the launch template to the above event.

I checked the other solution for checking the events for **CreateImage** and **RegisterImage** seems like they are triggered immediately as soon as you make the call.